# Limit height of div

Tags: css, html

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWZdD/) - As you can see, all divs heights are given in pixel (`div a` and `div b)`. Last one (div c)has `height:100%`, so its as high as all the body. I want it just to fill its parent, not to be as high as all the document. (yellow `div` is overflowing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div#b {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this does the trick

http://www.jsfiddle.net/KWZdD/30/

Comment: but i dont know when this 50px will change or someone will use larger set of fonts and then top-header div will get higher. Why is it not native? like width:100%. It just has to fill all the height. Cant say it any more simple.

Comment: `height: 100%` inherits the parent's height - `#c` is as high as `#a` and then pushed down 50px because of `#b`

Comment: It will be some column reader, horizontal webpage. That will adjust to user screen. Its preety tricky, but I cant hide overflow.

Comment: `floated` elements make the parent collapse - in your case, you can see it as if `#b` does not affect the container's height - almost like not taking space; so `#c` stretches exactly from top to bottom of its parent. `width: 100%` on `#b` makes it fill the parent width, its own content pushing down the content of `#c` (but not `#c` itself!)

Answer (score 0):

Put div c inside block a and take b out -

```
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="a">
     <div id="c"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you div a is the parent and it has the hight of 300px , so sum of b and c should be 300px

```
 #a{background:red; height:300px;}
 #b{background:blue; height:50px;}
 #c{background:yellow; height:250px; width:100px;}
```

Comment: Its just example. It will be fluid, responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KWZdD/28/)

It is as high as the body, including the b div. Fix it with negative margin and padding.

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
#a{background:red; height:300px;}
#b{background:blue; height:50px; position:relative; z-index:15;}
#c{background:yellow; height:100%; margin-top:-50px; padding-top: 50px;width:100px; position:relative; z-index:5;}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are coding to pixels, is there a reason why you don't want to set #c{height:250px;} ? That is, make Div C's height be the difference of Div A's height and Div B's Height? This would make sure that The yellow div always ends at the same height as the red div.

```
#a{background:red; height:300px;}
#b{background:blue; height:50px;}
#c{background:yellow; height:250px; width:100px;}​
```

Comment: It's just example... It will be responsive, fluid website. But thanks for your try